# LogonUser - inform users why login failed

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

Currently we have the following code:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string username, string domain, string password, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);
    bool isLoggedIn = LogonUser(...);
    if(isLoggedIn){
       // Some Code...
    } else {
       // Need to: 
       // If user entered incorrect password
       // If the user is locked/banned out of the system
    }
```

Our active directory config locks the users out after x failed login attempts. Is there any way to check whether the logon failed because the user entered the incorrect password, or because they were locked out due to too many attempts? Also, is there a way to request the number of attempts permitted by the AD? It seems our admins constantly change these numbers, so I don't want to hard-code them in the app

Comment: What library provides `LogonUser` ? Need a little more info in order to suggest a reasonable approach. It's certainly doable.

Comment: Please check my code edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return value

> If the function succeeds, the function returns nonzero. 
>   If the function fails, it returns zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

According to the documentation you should check for the last error. However, DO NOT p/invoke `GetLastError()` in C#, you should do it the managed way :

```
else
{
    // Need to: 
    // If user entered incorrect password
    // If the user is locked/banned out of the system

    var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    var exception = new Win32Exception(errorCode);

    // exception.Message should contain the information you need.
    // alternatively, you can switch on errorCode to provide your custom message
}
```

For reference you can look up the error code here : [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

> **Remarks** 
>   GetLastWin32Error exposes the Win32 GetLastError function from Kernel32.DLL. This method exists because it is not safe to make a direct platform invoke call to GetLastError to obtain this information. If you want to access this error code, you must call GetLastWin32Error instead of writing your own platform invoke definition for GetLastError and calling it. The common language runtime can make internal calls to APIs that overwrite the GetLastError maintained by the operating system.

Source: [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by suggesting not to p/invoke GetLastError()? The error codes I get seem to be consistent with what is going on. I can just have an if statement showing what's happened. Why do we need an exception?

Comment: @worldpart I updated my answer. You are supposed to create a new `Win32Exception` with the `errorCode` (see new edited code), this allow you to retrieve a friendly message about that error code. And, read the remarks that I have added.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thanks; did not bother with the exception, just switched over the error codes.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to throw the exception. It is just there to give you an idea what that error code means, but you could always look up the error code on msdn~

Comment: Yes, got it; looking up error codes did the trick; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for advapi32.dll you can get details about why the login failed by calling `GetLastError`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

ofc you'll have to add an extern for that method. Also, I recommend looking in the comments as someone has posted code to extract the text from the error which is likely what you'll want to display to the user.

Additionally you can use the `FormatMessage` method to produce a better error. It's linked to in the doc above but here's a direct link to it; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx